# JSON add text next to image

Tags: json, sharepoint, formatting, schema

I'm very new to JSON, and quite frankly I'm not sure how to properly set up my code.

**Goal**

Format a SharePoint column with country flags and display `@currentField` next to it.

**Current code**

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "img",
      "attributes": {
        "src": "='https://flagpedia.net/data/flags/h20/'+if(@currentField == 'AR','ar',if(@currentField == 'AT','at',if(@currentField == 'AU','au',if(@currentField == 'BE','be',if(@currentField == 'BG','bg',if(@currentField == 'BR','br',if(@currentField == 'BY','by',if(@currentField == 'CA','ca',if(@currentField == 'CH','ch',if(@currentField == 'CM','cm',if(@currentField == 'CN','cn',if(@currentField == 'CO','co',if(@currentField == 'CZ','cz',if(@currentField == 'DE','de',if(@currentField == 'DK','dk',if(@currentField == 'EC','ec',if(@currentField == 'EE','ee',if(@currentField == 'EG','eg',if(@currentField == 'ES','es',if(@currentField == 'FI','fi',if(@currentField == 'FR','fr',if(@currentField == 'GB','gb',if(@currentField == 'GR','gb',if(@currentField == 'GR','gr',if(@currentField == 'HR','hr',if(@currentField == 'HU','hu',if(@currentField == 'IE','ie',if(@currentField == 'IL','il',if(@currentField == 'IN','in',if(@currentField == 'IT','it',if(@currentField == 'LT','lt',if(@currentField == 'LU','lu',if(@currentField == 'LV','lv',if(@currentField == 'MX','mx',if(@currentField == 'NL','nl',if(@currentField == 'NO','no',if(@currentField == 'PA','pa',if(@currentField == 'PE','pe',if(@currentField == 'PL','pl',if(@currentField == 'PT','pt',,if(@currentField == 'RO','ro',if(@currentField == 'RU','ru',if(@currentField == 'SE','se',if(@currentField == 'SK','sk',if(@currentField == 'TR','tr',if(@currentField == 'US','us',if(@currentField == 'UY','uy',if(@currentField == 'ZA','za','no'))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))+ '.png'",
        "title": "@currentField"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I know it's messy, but this is they only way I know how to achieve the first part of what I'm after, as I'm not any good with JSON. This code provides the correct image for the correct value, although I'm sure it can be done way easier.

I applied this code into a columns' format section, to display the entered alpha2 country code as the respective country flag. It works fine, but I also wish to display the value of `@currentField` next to the image rather than "overwriting" with the flag.

I would post what I've tried so far, but quite frankly I'm clueless as to where to start. Looking for any pointers to the right direction, so I can figure out how to move forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the filed value is the alpha2 country code, so I made a test JSON in my end and works fine. Have a try with it and let me know if anything goes wrong.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType":"img",
      "attributes": {
        "src": "='https://flagpedia.net/data/flags/h20/'+ toLowerCase(@currentField)+'.png'"
   }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "style": {
        "padding-left": "6px",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "text-transform": "uppercase"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Looks like below:
[image]

Original view:
[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot. So you add another elm for the text part? By the way, the entries are from a multiple choice field, and are always uppercase. Need it to convert from upper case to lower case to get the png, I assume?

Comment: @HavardKleven, yes I add a span part for the text. I add a toLowerCase function so it shall work whaterver the original value is upper or lower case. Just in case the image source url is case Sensitive.

Comment: Hi, in this case it is indeed case sensitive. Thank you for the explanation and great answer. :-)